# Вызов шаблонной функции без аргументов

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Доброго времени суток.

Изучаю шаблоны в С++. Задача следующая - вызвать шаблонную функцию объявленную и реализованную в отдельном классе. Функция должна создавать и возвращать указатель на шаблонную структуру.

1.Код файла main.cpp с методом main():

```
    #include "ArrayList.h"
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        ArrayList<int>* list = initializeArrayList<int>();
        return 0;
    }
```

2. Код заголовочного файла ArrayList.h:

   ```
   template<class T> struct ArrayList;
   template<class T> ArrayList<T>* initializeArrayList();
   ```
3. Код файла ArrayList.cpp с реализацией функции initializeArrayList():

   ```
   #include "ArrayList.h"

   template<class T> struct ArrayList {
       T* array = new T*[10];
       int countItem = 0;
       int lengthArray = 10;
   };

   template<class T> ArrayList<T>* initializeArrayList() {
       return new ArrayList<T>;
   }
   ```

Компилирую через командную строку следующим образом:
g++ ArrayList.cpp main.cpp -o ArrayList.exe

Получаю ошибку компиляции со следующим содержанием:
undefined reference to `ArrayList* initializeArrayList()'

Объясните пожалуйста, где я допускаю ошибку и как правильно можно решить мою задачу.

Comment: Код шаблонных функций должен находится в ``*.h`` файлах. Перенесите весь код из cpp в h файл.

Comment: Просто на будущее: не существует «шаблонных» функций и структур. Есть _шаблоны_ функций и структур.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр. Вопрос можно считать закрытым.